# Best way to get another Facebook user's IP address

Tags: facebook, api

My Facebook application needs the IP Address of another user to communicate with that other user. So two users are using my application and one user wants to communicate with the other user. How does user A get the IP address of user B, or alternatively how does user B send its IP address to user A?

If this is not possible without passing the data manually is there a DB table that the IP address can be written to. My Facebook application has the ability to get its own local IP address. I just need a way to get the remote IP address using API's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook don't have support for any custom data storage, you will need to handle this on your own in your applications server code.

Basically you will need to have a database (or similar storage) where you store facebook user id and IP-address.

Another note is that you can't get another Facebook users IP-address from Facebook, you need to get it from your connection to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have both users connect to a server of your choice, register the IPs there.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not supply users' IP addresses, so you'll need to handle this on your own.  You should be able to retrieve this from the HTTP request headers your users submit.  Check the source IP and store it in a database, then use that to send to the other user.

Comment: Its the "then use that to send to the other user."  bit I want to work, I am already able to get my IP Address from my FB app but I would like a way to send that to the other user's same app or vice versa.  From all your help it seems to do this I have to use my own backend system.  I would have thought FB has some application IPC mechanism for passing data between apps.  I don't mean the request\response API but something more app specific.